Identifying plaster and drywall for patching strategy
We just moved into a house built in the 1920s. I would expect the walls to be plaster and they (some of them?) might be. There is lath back there, if you look deep enough, in some places. But the crumbling around holes looks like wallboard.  An electrician speculated they may have put the wallboard over plaster, at least in the bathroom ceiling. Ultimately, we need to patch a hole and there is no lath there.  Should we just treat this material like drywall as there is no lath behind the hole?



I'm guessing that the black is an ancient glue and not mold.  Am I correct?

Ohhh I don't know.   I was going to clean and Kilz.

If it doesn't come off easily it is probably glue.  I have seen old (1950s) kitchen and baths with some odd composite plastic tile glued up with a black glue.  What was covering it?

If there is no lath you would have to treat the repair like it was drywall. The eazy fix would be adding a piece of scrap wood behind the hole.
Gluing in a rectangle of drywall. Then taping and mudding. Spread the mud out at least 6 inches past the edge of the tape to make a smooth transition.
Apply your finish. If it is tile or another solid covering, you don't need to worry about it being "pretty".
